# iOS App Does Not Detect Device Orientation Change

Tags: ios, uideviceorientation

I have an issue with orientation change in my app. My app supports Portrait, LandscapeLeft and LandscapeRight Device Orientations, which I am 100% sure that I configure it properly in the Info.plist. When I run my app on my iPhone/Simulator, and rotate the device, none of my app ViewControllers responses to the rotation. That is, no ViewControllers can be changed to Landscape Mode regardless of how hard and crazy I rotate my phone. I tried to override the 'Autorotate' var to return true/false, same result, My app stick to single Portrait Mode, which is not what I want. So I was thinking maybe my app couldn't even detect the Device Orientation Change; therefore, I put the following code in my AppDelegate, and I was right, func "deviceOrientationDidChange" is never called when I rotate my phone, but it's called when app enter background. Anyone has any clues? I have been struggling with this for days, and trying to find a solution from internet, but no hope. Please help.

```
UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
let notifiCenter = NotificationCenter.default
notifiCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.deviceOrientationDidChange(_:)), name: .UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)

func deviceOrientationDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("device orientation did change...")
}
```

Comment: Is your 'root' view controller a NavController? a TabBarController? a Single View Controller? Are you doing anything else in AppDelegate, like setting status bar properties? Are you using Storyboard? If so, if you (temporarily) add a new Storyboard and a new, simple UIViewController, does *that* rotate properly?

Comment: My app provide authentication. When users are authenicated, the rootViewController is TabBarController. Otherwise, rootViewController is UIPageViewController. Yes, I use Storyboard, and most of my VC connected to the Main Storyboard. I have this line in my AppDelegate: "application.statusBarOrientation = .portrait" to force the app launch in portrait mode. I tried to remove that line, the viewControllers still behave the same way.

Comment: hmmm... makes me wonder if there's another (or a couple) instance of `application.statusBarOrientation = .portrait` somewhere in your code. If you  remove that line from AppDelegate, and launch your app on an iPad already in landscape orientation, does it still launch in portrait?

Comment: I did a search with keyword "statusBarOrientation", that's the only place has it. I actually tried a programmatically Device Orientation Change, and it worked. ViewControllers did rotate to Landscape mode.

Comment: To me, the problem seems like my application is ignoring the Device Orientation Change or just not being notified. I put the code from this question in my App. It's very strange that the observer func is never called, when I rotate my phone. But it's called when the app didEnterBackground or willEnterForeground. Very strange to me.

Comment: Give this a try, and see what kinds of messages you get (too much code for a comment, but it's not an answer...):  https://gist.github.com/DonMag/1f0ebbd0824337a1408fb265c9e16c48

Comment: It printed a list of Notification as expected, and UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification is one of them. But when I rotated my phone, the showNotifs(_:) is not called. Like I mentioned before, the orientationDidChange Notification is sent when the app enter forgeground or background, but not when I rotate my iphone.

Comment: Yes, very odd... are you using some 3rd-party library that's somehow doing not-nice things to your app? Did you try temporarily changing the startup storyboard and view controller as I suggested earlier?

Comment: Yup, I had many 3rd party frameworks installed. That's def the first thing came to my mind, 3rd party framework can extend classes that change the ordinary behavior of the classes. I am seeking for help to see what might change the behavior of a DeviceOrientationChange Notification, so I can go back to my app and see if there are codes that change that behavior. Right now, I don't even know how to find if any frameworks cause any misbehavior. I did play around with the relevant var 'Autorotate', 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation' and 'supportedInterfaceOrientations'.

Comment: OK - well... sorry, but I don't know how to offer any more assistance. I suppose my last suggestion would be to start a new project, add in the 3rd-party frameworks one at a time until you run into the same issue with your new project. Then you'll know.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much for your time and help. Really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still couldn't figure out what the causes really are, but this issue did get fixed after I Pod Update all the pod frameworks used in my app. I really tried so hard to try to find out what causes this issue. Unfortunately, I couldn't. I have about 20 3rd-party frameworks installed via pod. My fix to this issue is Pod Update. No luck on what the causes are. Hope this answer will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but normally using:

`override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        // Do more stuff
    }`

Should be enough to catch a callback when rotation changes, since view size changes too.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had tried this. The problem I am having right now is, no ViewControllers can even detect the orientation change, viewWillTransition is never called either.

Comment: Try using that function in your viewcontroller and put a breakpoint to check if works when rotation change.

Comment: Yes. I had tried that. If you look at my code from this question. The problem seems like that the ViewControllers are NOT even notified that the device orientation is changed. Just to clarify, Orientation Change works fine for other apps run on my phone, and Portrait Orientation Lock is Off on my iPhone.